# Hiding symbols in a shared library on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries, new-operator, gnu

We've been building a large open source [software](http://appleseedhq.net/) on a variety of platforms (Linux, Windows, Mac OS X, 32-bit and 64-bit) for several years without troubles. Lately however, the Mac OS X build (64-bit) stopped working correctly and started to crash randomly. It more or less coincided with an update of Mac OS X on our build machine from 10.7 to 10.8.2 (but the compiler toolchain didn't change, it's still llvm-gcc 4.2.1).

Our application is made of a couple of dynamic (shared) libraries and many executables using them. One of the shared library overrides the `new` and `delete` operators for a variety of reasons. On Mac OS X (and Linux), all symbols are exported by default, including our overloaded `new` and `delete` operators. The crashes on Mac OS X seem related to some memory being allocated with one memory subsystem (not ours) then freed through our own (and incompatible) `delete` implementation.

The sanest solution seems to be preventing the overloaded operators from being visible to the users of the shared library. This can be accomplished in two ways: marking the operators with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`, or using the `-unexported_symbols_list` linker command line option to prevent some symbols from being exported. The first solution unfortunately doesn't work: gcc emits warnings saying that the operators have been declared differently (in `<new>`) and thus the attributes will be ignored. From my readings in various places, **the second solution seems to be the right one to this problem. However for some reason we can't make it work**.

When linking the shared library, we're passing the `-Wl,-unexported_symbols_list unexported_symbols_list.txt` option to g++, which in turns should be passed to ld. The `unexported_symbols_list.txt` file contains the following list of symbols:

```
__ZdaPv
__ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t
__ZdlPv
__ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t
__ZdlPvS_
__Znam
__ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t
__Znwm
__ZnwmPv
__ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t
```

These are all the variations of `new` and `delete` that we override and want to be hidden. We found these symbols by doing `nm libappleseed.dylib` then unmangling the symbol names using `c++filt`.

Here's the command line generated by CMake to link `libappeseed.dylib`:

```
/usr/bin/g++  -g -Werror -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -framework Cocoa -lcurl    -Werror -Wl,-unexported_symbols_list -Wl,unexported_symbols_list.txt -o ../mac-gcc4/appleseed/libappleseed.dylib [...]
```

**Unfortunately, despite all our efforts it appears that the symbols remain (as nm shows).**

Any idea what we are doing wrong?
Is there another approach that we could try?

---

**UPDATE Dec. 19, 2012:**

Our problem and the supposed solution are well covered in this technical note from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2185/_index.html (section "Overriding new/delete").

Pointers to relevant source code:

- `operator new` and `operator delete` overrides: [allocator.cpp](https://github.com/jupiter-jazz/appleseed/blob/0ae130df5750c468db80f7fcdae40bb82bc0b23a/src/appleseed/main/allocator.cpp#L480)
- Macros to control symbol visibility in the shared library: [dllvisibility.h](https://github.com/jupiter-jazz/appleseed/blob/a9fcc42c52548b01507823e966b2a4b5861f7af4/src/appleseed/main/dllvisibility.h#L33)

Fragment of `nm`'s output after building libappleseed.dylib with `-fvisibility=hidden` and running `strip -x libappleseed.dylib`:

```
...
00000000002a41b0 T __ZdaPv
00000000002a41f0 T __ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t
00000000002a4190 T __ZdlPv
00000000002a41d0 T __ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t
00000000002a4060 T __Znam
00000000002a4130 T __ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t
00000000002a3ff0 T __Znwm
00000000002a40d0 T __ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t
...
```

Comment: Can you drop the relevant lines from nm which shows that the symbols are still there?

Comment: Sure, the lines are in the update above. Not only are the offending symbols still there, but the application continues to crash randomly.

Comment: You've undoubtedly looked at this already, but I notice a comma separating `-unexported_symbols_list` from the name of the file in the g++ command line - that's not breaking it?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Each linker argument must be prefixed by `-Wl,`. As far as I can see there is no extra comma. Thanks for having a look though.

Answer (score 7):

You should be building with `-fvisibility=hidden` and then export only what you want. Have a read here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

It also explains `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden`. Many large libraries (Qt, for example) make use of this. The benefits are quite substantial.

Comment: This is something we'd like to do eventually. I was under the impression that gcc's visibility syntax was incompatible with Visual C++'s one (i.e. visibility attributes were used in different places in declarations) but it appears from this document that I was wrong (or the situation improved since last time I checked). Thanks for pointing this out, we'll probably go this route eventually. **That's a rather important change to apply and test though, so we'd still be interested in a quick interim solution**.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune I suppose using `-unexported_symbol symbol` multiple times instead of using a file doesn't work either? (For example `-unexported_symbol __ZdaPv -unexported_symbol __ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t [...]`)

Comment: So we tried using `-unexported_symbol symbol` (by passing e.g. `-Wl,-unexported_symbol -Wl,__ZdaPv` to g++) but to no avail. The arguments are properly passed down to ld, but nm shows that the symbols remain in the generated library file. Our conclusions so far are that: either the linker is not ld (g++ actually invokes `collect2` instead of `ld`), ld on OS X doesn't really support these flags, or we're making a stupid mistake (but we tried many different things all leading to the same conclusions). Any idea/hint would be very much appreciated. We'll offer a bounty as soon as we're allowed.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune Also try: `-Xlinker -unexported_symbol -Xlinker __ZdaPv -Xlinker -unexported_symbol -Xlinker __ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t ...` ld on OS X does support the `-unexported_symbol` flag. Another thing to check is whether you need to strip the resulting library in order for those symbols to be removed. Also check the flags `strip` supports and whether you need some specific ones for stripping libraries.

Comment: Thanks, we'll try that as well, although it appears to be a synonym to `-Wl,`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221141/any-difference-between-wl-option-and-xlinker-option-syntax-for-gcc. Also we have already checked that the options are correctly passed to the linker by enabling verbosity on g++. We'll also investigate whether stripping makes a difference (I hope not). Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: An update on this (yet unresolved) issue: we're now building with `-fvisibility=hidden` but the problem persists: according to `nm`, the `new` and `delete` operators are still visible. Stripping the shared library doesn't seem to have any effect. Bounty opened.

Comment: It looks like `strip -x libappleseed.dylib` had an effect (the symbol list went from 5 MB to 2 MB), however it appears that the new/delete operators are still there, as indicated by `nm`: for instance `nm`'s output shows `00000000002a41b0 T __ZdaPv` where the T stands for "text section symbol". The application still crashes.

Comment: We still didn't figure out the problem, but we eventually decided to no longer override the `new` and `delete` operators since memory blocks are natively 16-byte-aligned on Mac OS X and Linux anyway (our primary reason to provide our own allocation functions). @NikosC I'm attributing you the bounty for your help and many suggestions, thanks again.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune Thanks. But I'm sorry to hear the problem is still unsolved. I suppose some form of paid support from Apple (if they even offer that) is out of the question?

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune I just found a detail in the docs that I didn't notice before: "Note that due to ISO C++ specification requirements, operator new and operator delete must always be of default visibility." Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at symbol maps/versioning (--version-script ld option)

http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1372

Comment: Thanks. That aspect of things should already be taken care of with gcc's  `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` attributes.

Comment: It seems --version-script is (still) not supported clang/llvm to this date.

Comment: @codesniffer can you please confirm that --version-script is not suppoted in xcode clang cpp build, tnx

Comment: @Boki I get build errors for --version-script on 10.10, 10.12, and 10.15, and I don't see it in the man page.  It shouldn't matter, but I'm using only XCode CLT.  ld version on my 10.15 system is LLVM version 11.0.0, (clang-1100.0.33.17).  Is it working for you?

Comment: @codesnifer Ok, thanks, I am just about planning to refactor some code for build with XCode 11.3 on 10.15, cause I experienced issues/crashes with dlclose when executing app on HighSierra or Mohave(no issues on Catalina). So, for beginning, my idea was to reduce/control exports using version scripts. I used to think about, when I saw your comment here, but, I think I noticed earlier, some options in BuildSettings for linker map scripts or similar, I am not sure, I will recheck during weekend anyway. If I find  something useful I will keep you informed.